# How can I remove the bluetooth setup wizard on a headless Mac Mini?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac-mini

I finally moved my old Mini into the back room on a TV.  I use Air Mouse to control it from my iOS devices.

However, with no keyboard and mouse connected it seems to bring up the bluetooth setup wizard each time I wake it from sleep.  This is a 2007 (core duo 1.83) running the latest Snow Leopard.

How do I disable this behavior or utility?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Bluetooth?

Comment: @KyleCronin You know, I hadn't even thought of that.  Duh!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable the Bluetooth Setup Wizard by:

- Go to System Preferences
- Click Bluetooth
- Click Advanced
- Un-check 'Open Bluetooth Setup Assistant at start up when no input device is present'.

The screen should look like this (the checkbox above the highlighted section):
[image: advanced bluetooth]

More information in this Apple KB - [Wireless Input Devices](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3887#wakeup)

Also, if you are not using Bluetooth at all, you can disable it as well.